# macOS -- How to install plugin in .vimrc

Tags: macos, vim, plugins

If I want to add and install a plugin in my Vim on macOS, what should I write in .vimrc?

And after write the code in .vimrc, what command should I write?

Comment: Every single Vim plugin provides installation instructions.

Comment: That's completely depending on the plugin manager which you are using. From Vim 8 there is a built-in plugin manager, however, I'd suggest you to use plugin manager such as junegunn/vim-plug, k-takata/minpac etc.

Comment: A widely held opinion among veteran Vimmers is that you shouldn't install plugins before you stop needing them. If you don't know how to install a plugin, it's likely too early to be leaving vanilla Vim.

Comment: [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange – How do I install a plugin in Vim/vi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi)

Answer (score -2):

I recommend `spf13`. It integrated almost every plugins you needed.

run following command to install

or you can read their github: 
https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim